# jPlayer doesn't play second time on iOS (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, jplayer

I am developing webapplication using Node.js with Express. On main page, there are 4 possible options to choose (4 links) - for every of them, there is a previously hidden div (visibility: hidden), that shows after clicking a link (it's moreless div pop-up).

In that div, there is a media player - jPlayer, which streams a mp3 file piped through backend (file is originally on S3).

It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but there are some problems with using it with iOS.
Example fail scenario:
1. clicking 1st link
2. clicking play on media player (it plays well)
3. closing the pop-up div
4. clicking 3rd link
5. clicking play on media player (it doesn't play, however the play button is switched on, as if it is playing).

From what I have already read, it may be problem of using media player on hidden layer.
How can I repair that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have moved the jplayer outside the pop-ups, and left only javascript links to change the tracks in player and play them.

It works well on all platforms.